# Non-dev-tools Windows Phone 7 emulation

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

In developing a number of WP7 apps, I have a need to show clients how the app will be when deployed. The clients are **a)** not in the same location as I am, **b)** not technical at all, and **c)** may not even be using a PC. The purpose is to demo, get feedback and make any needed changes.

I'm not finding any realistic options to just simply show them what it would look, feel and run on a Windows Phone 7 (using the `ApplicationBar`, etc.). I found this link - http://www.redmondpie.com/standalone-windows-phone-7-series-emulator-9140536/ - but it's rather hacky for me to ask someone to do to set up an emulator on their machine without also installing VS Express, etc.

Does anyone know of any links to an official emulator that can be run on a PC, has a simple install and can load WP7 apps?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a product such as Citrix GoTo.  Clients do not need to be particularly technical to join such a meeting, you can then take them through a demo.  This will cost you though.

A free alternative would be to set aside a PC running the emulator with your software loaded.  Create a VPN for you clients to connect to and let them use Remote Desktop Connection to connect to the PC.  They can then play around with it remotely.

Comment: Definitely, that's my current solution (LiveMeeting). It's a little clunky because of some screen updating lag. I like the Remote Desktop idea though.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [SketchFlow](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Sketchflow_Overview.aspx)?  Although by default the UI is "sketchy" (sorry), you can apply styles to the controls you drop on your pages, including the very same styles that are used by Windows Phone controls.

If you use a Silverlight SketchFlow project, you can deploy the content to a web server and provide a link that can be consumed on any machine that will render Silverlight content...they can go through the navigation, provide feedback, etc.

Christian Schormann has a writeup on what is required to use it in the pre-release tools... http://electricbeach.org/?p=573

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting angle to consider. I'm not sure if the client would accept that as the request is not for prototyping, but rather alpha/beta testing.

Comment: When I woke up this morning, I realized that my answer is probably not what you're after...sorry about that.  You have a Silverlight Assembly for the phone, and want to host it outside of the phone.  The problem is that all of the API's, etc that are used are not part of the CoreCLR (eg if you kick open one of the launchers or choosers.)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this: http://justinangel.net/WindowsPhone7EmulatorAutomation. I believe it will answer your question exactly.

Comment: perfect, just what I was looking for!